# Remove context awareness from Web API controller

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

Suppose that i have

```
public IQueryable<Application> GetApplications() {
    var applications = _context.Applications.Where(v => v.Exported == false);
    // Now i want to flag exported = true because i am exporting them
    foreach (var application in applications){
        _context.Applications.SingleOrDefault(v => v.ApplicationId == application .ApplicationId).Exported = true;
}
    _context.SaveChanges();
    return applications;
}
```

I am not getting any applications because _context.SaveChanges(); ( i suppose) changed the applications variable.
How can i change the Database without changing my local variable.

Comment: Well that seems very weird and should not happen. Make sure that `applications` is not empty collection at first line of method.

Comment: its not empty. while debugging i can see the applications variable populated and after SaveChanges applications is empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call `ToList` to execute query before changing items:

```
var applications = _context.Applications.Where(v => v.Exported == false).ToList();
```